# Pandas index clause across multiple columns in a multi-column header

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame with multi-column headers.

```
import pandas as pd

headers = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A", "u"), ("A", "v"), ("B", "x"), ("B", "y")])
f = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0]], columns = headers)
f
    A     B   
    u  v  x  y
 0  1  1  0  1
 1  1  0  0  0
 2  0  0  1  1
 3  1  0  1  0
```

I want to select the rows in which either all the A columns or all the B columns are true.
I can do so explicitly.

```
f[f["A"]["u"].astype(bool) | f["A"]["v"].astype(bool)]
   A     B   
   u  v  x  y
0  1  1  0  1
1  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  1  0

f[f["B"]["x"].astype(bool) | f["B"]["y"].astype(bool)]
   A     B   
   u  v  x  y
0  1  1  0  1
2  0  0  1  1
3  1  0  1  0
```

I want to write a function `select(f, top_level_name)` where the indexing clause applies to all the columns under the same top level name such that

```
select(f, "A") == f[f["A"]["u"].astype(bool) | f["A"]["v"].astype(bool)]
select(f, "B") == f[f["B"]["x"].astype(bool) | f["B"]["y"].astype(bool)]
```

I want this function to work with arbitrary numbers of sub-columns with arbitrary names.

How do I write `select`?

Comment: Do you mean [any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)? Like `f[f['A'].astype(bool).any(axis=1)]` and `f[f['B'].astype(bool).any(axis=1)]`?

Comment: @HenryEcker's solution is concise enough for your use case

Comment: Yes. That works.